# How to integrate KendoGrid and Chart

Tags: html, kendo-ui

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="search" />
<div id="grid">


<div id="chart"/>

$("#chart").kendoChart({});
var gridResult = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: { data: database },
    columns: [
        {
            field: "id",
            title: "ID"
        },
        {
            field: "x",
            title: "x"
        },
        {
            field: "y"
        },
        {
            field: "z"
        },
        {
            field: "p"
        }
    ]
});

$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    $filter = new Array();
    $x = $("#txtSearch").val();
    if ($x) {
        $filter.push({ field:"x", operator:"contains", value:$x});
    }
    gridResult.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter($filter);
});
```

Now based on the value I searched in text box it is appearing in grid and the result what I got in grid should update to chart. I am struggling with how to integrate Kendo grid and chart in HTML5.

I am new to HTML5.

Because I need to filter the values in grid and based on filtered values chart should update.

Comment: Hi i had updated so far what i have did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize the grid, are you able to display searched content in the textbox? You write change event in the grid and get the value. In the change function you initialize the chart and update it.

Comment: how to write the change function in grid as I am new to kendo.

Comment: var Grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({ dataSource: datasource,  selectable: "multiple", columns: [], change: function () {    var grid = this;  grid.select().each(function () { var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this)); text += dataItem.id; })};  });

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared DataSource. Please check [this demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/datasource/shared-datasource.html).